# Querying primary keys

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Please I have following results below, seven columns with a `primary key (reg_num)`:

```
reg_num day Morning Midday  Lunch   Evening Total_Period
0983776412  3   Yes Yes No  Yes 3
0985674389  3   No  Yes No  No  1
0983464736  4   Yes No  Yes No  2
0983466827  11  No  No  No  No  0
0983481234  15  Yes Yes Yes Yes 4
```

Each row shows a combination of 'yes' and 'no' for a single day per `reg_num`. You will see the last column "`Total_Period`" is a count of all the '`yes`' in each row.

Please do you know how I can calculate the value for "`Total_Period`"?

Comment: total `Total_Period` or total `Total_Period` per `day` or total `Total_Period` per `reg_num`??

Comment: For total `Total_Period` try ::  `select sum(Total_Period) from your_table`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Total_Period should count only 'Yes' either in 'Morning', 'Midday', 'Lunch' and 'Evening'. Hence 'day 4' has a 'Total_Period' of 2 because that record has 'Yes' in 'Morning' and 'Midday'. Hope this helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way is:

```
select decode(Morning, 'Yes', 1, 0)  + 
       decode(Midday, 'Yes', 1, 0)   + 
       decode(Lunch, 'Yes', 1, 0)    + 
       decode(Evening , 'Yes', 1, 0) 
from your_table
```

Comment: YES! That fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try ORACLE REGULAR exp also if your DB is 11G and above. Hope it is helpful.

```
SELECT a.reg_no,
  a.dy,
  a.morning,
  a.middday,
  a.lunch,
  a.evening,
  REGEXP_COUNT(a.morning
  ||','
  ||a.middday
  ||','
  ||a.lunch
  ||','
  ||a.evening,'Yes') Total_Period
FROM
  (SELECT 0983776412 reg_no,
    3 dy,
    'Yes' AS morning,
    'Yes' AS middday,
    'No' lunch ,
    'Yes' evening,
    NULL AS Total_Period
  FROM dual
  )A;
```